# How can i compare the checked day and current day?

Tags: c#

Now iam stuck with a problem.

I have a checked listbox having weekdays sunday,monday etc..

This is my code for populating checked items from database.

```
string[] setday = dr.GetValue(2).ToString().Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < setday.Length - 1; i++)
{
  days.SetItemChecked(Convert.ToInt32(setday[i]), true);
}
```

And i have a save button when i click the save button i insert the index of checked days to my database table.then i have a compare button to compare when i click this i want to know today is checked or not.

How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nearly not enough information. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: my problem is i want to know today is checked or not from the checkedlistbox

Comment: then compare your checkboxlist date to system.datetime.now

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide much information but still I guess this what you want

I assume that you will fetch a string of days from database like this

```
"sun,mon,tue,thu,fri,sat"
```

and in front end want to check days according to that string. If this is the situation than try this out

**Front end**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chks">
  <asp:ListItem>sun</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>mon</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>tue</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>thu</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>fri</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>sat</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**Back end**

```
string[] days = "sun,mon,tue,thu,fri,sat".Split(',');
ListItem[] chkdays = new ListItem[chks.Items.Count];
chks.Items.CopyTo(chkdays, 0);
chkdays.ToList().ForEach(delegate(ListItem item)
       {
           item.Selected = days.Contains(item.Text);
       });
```

Comment: this example is for asp.net my program is a windows application.

Comment: @Arunkumar that's why I've said about nearly not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to check current date's day of week and compare it against the checked listbox value. Refer to this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx) on how to get DayOfWeek for a date.